# Is there any planet modelling software?

Tags: planets, map-making, software-recommendations

I am searching for a software capable of creating any planet ( like universe sandbox) with the ability of shaping the landscape and adding tags to any coordinates I wish to in order to represent cities, important places, etc. It would be even better if I could assign pre-designed icons to them.

I've searched the entire internet but found nothing satisfying. I want a software that is simple and easy to use. I am not searching a mere map design software in 2D , but a globe creator (or something like that).

If anybody can find something like that, I would be very grateful for the rest of my life :)

**edit:** Sorry for not responding for quite a month. I've been busy with my studies. user23614 thanks for **campaign cartographer** seems perfectly fit to me. **Fractal Terrain add-on** seems what I've looked for. Thank you alot :) The only bemol is that I can't put symbols (of cities, military facilities, ICBM bases etc.) on a global scale. But I can export maps from the planet I create. That's a thing!

**edit 2**: I figured out how to add tags after exporting my globe to google earth. But It only works on google maps site. Any idea how I can change things (add borders, tags etc) in actual google earth software?

Comment: Welcome to the site Alihan, we have quite a few questions on this topic.  http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/24004/what-software-can-help-me-render-a-planet-from-space or http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125/what-software-is-available-for-map-creation?rq=1 may be a good start for you.

Comment: The ***entire*** internet, eh? Impressive.

Comment: AndreiROM yeah its a manner of speaking :)                                                             James thank you for these topics, but they are not entirely fitting what I search for. I would still want to see what other possibilites are.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add @James' links to your question with some explanation of how they are not what you want.  As it is, you may have a clear picture of what you want your software to do, but we don't.  When I read your question, Terragen seems to fit.  What should your software do that Terragen doesn't?  Could it be solved by using Terragen with the results of a 2D map creator?  If not, why not?

Comment: Campaign Cartographer from Profantasy with add ons Cosmographer and Fractal Terrain could well fit the bill

Comment: Note that, to some extent, [Digital Sculpting tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_sculpting) might be able to fit the bill. The most questionable thing would be "tagging". You can assign colors to areas(*faces*), which may be sufficient. Otherwise it would be fairly simple to "sculpt" a planet.

Comment: As others have noted, this seems a bit vague or too broad. It would help if you give some details on what is wrong/missing with what you have found so far in your searches. Also more details of what you expect from "shaping the landscape" (e.g. do you want to draw all rivers, coastlines mountains etc from scratch, or need help from the software - and if so, how much - and how detailed). Worldbuilding is not a mainstream activity and everyone is interested in very different aspects, so there is not much mainstream or simple software available.

Comment: Just a quick observation...  Generally, easy to use software is less capable.  So  be prepared to make some compromises on capabilities if you require the software to be easy to use.

Comment: Sorry for not responding for quite a month. I've been busy with my studies.                                                                                                           user23614 thanks for campaign cartographer seems perfectly fit to me. Fractal Terrain add-on seems what I've looked for.  Thank you alot :)                   The only bemol is that I can't put symbols (of cities, military facilities, ICBM bases etc.) on a global scale. But I can export maps from the planet I create. That's a thing!

Comment: sorry for flooding, I figured out how to add tags after exporting my globe to google earth. But It only works on google maps site. Any idea how I can change things (add borders, tags etc) in actual google earth software?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to create a 3D landscape, for any random use, I have something that might work. It's more of a graphic-oriented tool but it may be useful to you. It was useful to me on the past, at least!

It's called Bryce 3D. It's currently on its 7th iteration, and it is a pretty powerful tool for shaping landscapes.

Now, I used it way back then (in the times of Bryce 3D 4), but it was a really majestic tool!

It can shape any landscape you want with a ton of terraforming tools. It can add individual trees, raise mountains, add lakes and much, much more!

[You can check it out here.](http://www.daz3d.com/bryce-7-pro)

If you need something more... flatty, like, say, an Atlas, them you have plenty of options.

My favorite tool is [RPGMaker](http://www.rpgmakerweb.com/). While it was devised as a game-making tool, its map designer is simply uber-easy to use and really powerful. You only will be able to create some retro-style maps, sure, but hey, they are pretty awesome anyway!

Now, if you really need to create *globes*, that's something different. I'm not sure how you want to use them (if you tell us more I may be able to pinpoint a better tool), but if your idea is to create a 3D Galaxy, them check out Bryce 3D and its Deep Space Add-On pack. You can remove the default land and create a void, and them put the globes on the sky and shape them at will.

If you need something simpler than that... well, we need more details to help you! If you say how you intend to use your globes, I may be able to pinpoint just the tool you need!

[Oh, and there is Terragen, too.](http://planetside.co.uk/products/terragen3)